# Permissions inheritance problems with Windows 10

Tags: windows, permissions, icacls

Since upgrading to Windows 10, I have moved over my hard drive from Windows 8.1 which contained my Users folder. I have previously made migrations like this with no issues, but this time, I'm getting some permissions problems.

While generally speaking it doesn't make too much difference, some programs are unable to save files correctly.

When I migrated the hard drive, I removed the permissions of the old users, took ownership on my account, and added my account to have Full Control. I also ticked 'Replace all child permission entries with inheritable entries from this object'.

That last bit doesn't seem to work properly.

I now find that all files under this folder (D:\Users\Me) will have the correct permissions for my account, but further subfolders and subfolders of those will not have the inherited full control permission from my account. Instead, they have full control for Administrators, and Read/Execute for Users which oddly are inherited from D:\Users and D:\Users\Me respectively.

So why do administrator and generic user permissions inherit correctly, but my permissions don't? Is there a way I can just blank the permissions and start fresh with all files and folders inheriting from the parent?

Comment: Do you took ownership on subfolders and files?

Comment: I did. I actually managed to solve this - it seems to be a bug in Windows and I'm not entirely sure if what I did was a fluke or not. I disabled inheritance on the top level directory and let that filter down, then I re-enabled inheritance and found that my permissions had propagated correctly. Previously I had tried wiping all the permissions, backing up the files and restoring them without permissions entries, and other tricks all to no avail.